# Proving that $G\simeq G/H\oplus G/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I want to prove that for a group $G$ and normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ where $H\cap K = \{e\}$
$$
G \simeq G/H\oplus G/K.
$$

My thought is to use the map $g \mapsto (gH,gK)$. I can show that this is a homomorphism because $G/H$ and $G/K$ are groups. I can also show this is an isomorphism: This follows from $H\cap K = \{e\}$. So $gH = g'H$ and $gK = g'K$ implies that $g^{-1}g' \in H\cap K$.

But how can I show that the map is surjective?

Comment: Shouldn't "isomorphism" in "I can show this an isomorphism" be "monomorphism"?

Comment: This doesn't seem true. If $G=(G')^3$ for some group $G'$, with $H$ being the first component ($G'\oplus \{e\}\oplus \{e\}$), and $K$ being the second component, then $G/H\oplus G/K\simeq (G')^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is injective, since the kernel is $H\cap K$. But it is not surjective without other hypotheses. For instance, in an abelian group, all subgroups are normal, but $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)\times\mathbf Z/r\mathbf Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z$ since the former has $pqr$ elements and the latter $pq$.

Another counter example is this: any two subgroups $H,K$ of a group $G$ with *distinct* prime orders $p$ and $q$ intersect trivially. There does not result that $G\simeq H\times K$: otherwise, it would mean that any group with two subgroups of prime orders $p$ and $q$ has order $pq$, which is absurd (what if $G$ has $3$ subgroups of distinct prime orders?)

Comment: Would you make this a bit more explicit?

Comment: I've added a few arguments. Is that clearer?

Comment: Thank you! I am still a bit confused about what $G$, $H$ and $K$ is in your first example.

Comment: $G$ is the product of the $3$ cyclic groups, $H$ the product of the first two, and $K$ the third cyclic group.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that OP meant to assume that $G=KH$.

Comment: It was not clear at all for me… Anyway he/she must learn to formulate precisely the hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume (in addition to what you did) that $HK=G$, then, since $H$ is normal and $H\cap K$ is trivial, $G=H\rtimes K$. What is left is to show that the action of $K$ (by conjugation) on $H$ is trivial.

Then you only need to show that $khk^{-1}h^{-1}=e$ (for all appropriate $k,h$). For that, you need to use normality of $K$ and $H$.

This will imply that $G=K\oplus H$. But then obviously $G/H\cong K$ and $G/K\cong H$